Can I enable Wayland sharing from the command line?
Is there any way to enable Wayland sharing from the command line? When I try to access Ubuntu 22.04 LTS with Teamviewer it's blocked because of this popup on the target:

Note that removing a monitor doesn't help, it just reduces the list to one - you still have to click Share to enable the connection.
I can SSH into Ubuntu using Tailscale so is there any way of accepting this dialog from the command line so I can get Teamviewer access?

What about using the integrated RDP server instead? That will allow you to login straight into the desktop (at least with one monitor, not sure what would happen with two monitors, but it's worth a shot)

try gsettings command line

Just figured this out. I used ssh to login to Ubuntu then did:
sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf

In this file I changed:
[daemon]
AutomaticLoginEnable=False

to:
[daemon]
AutomaticLoginEnable=True

I saved the file then did:
sudo service gdm3 restart

I am  now able to login to Ubuntu with TeamViewer.
